# How to get my systemd service restarted when its dependency is upgraded

Tags: systemd, services, dependencies

I've written a program that uses a Postgres database, and I wrote a systemd service file for it. Currently my service gets started on boot just fine, and it gets stopped when Postgres is stopped for upgrading (by `apt upgrade`). However, when the upgrade is complete and Postgres is started again, my service is not automatically started.

**Can I define some dependency to get my service started again automatically?**

This is the status of my service after it was automatically stopped during the Postgres upgrade:

```
● tabill.service - My service
   Loaded: loaded (/srv/tabill/tabill.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-07-04 00:29:24 EEST; 44min ago
 Main PID: 1048 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
```

Note that I can manually start the service again just fine.

Here's my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
Wants=nginx.service
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/srv/tabill/app/serve
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried adding `PartOf=postgresql.service` and `BindsTo=postgresql.service`, and then manually stopping and starting Postgres, but neither helped.

Of course I could remove the `Requires`, but stopping both services together is preferable, if only they would both start back up.

Comment: `PartOf=` sounds like the right solution. Did you try it with `Requires=` removed?

Comment: @meuh I tried it now with `Requires=` removed, that didn't help. I think the problem is that `PartOf=` links "stopping and restarting of units", but Postgres isn't **restarted** during an upgrade. It's stopped, upgraded, and started.

Comment: Amusingly enough, when you do `systemctl restart postgresql`, systemd remembers to restart its dependent services again. It seems like apt, for some reason, does combination of `stop` and `start` instead of `restart`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer: I needed to change the last line of the service file to:

```
WantedBy=postgresql.service
```

This way, whenever Postgres is started, my service is started too - but if my service fails, that doesn't stop Postgres.

Directives in the `[Install]` section only affect enabling and disabling of units. But it wasn't this simple when my service was already enabled:

```
# systemctl enable tabill.service
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The error message was misleading. Fixing it was simple:

```
# systemctl disable tabill.service
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/tabill.service.
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tabill.service.

# systemctl enable tabill.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

# systemctl enable /srv/tabill/tabill.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service.wants/tabill.service to /srv/tabill/tabill.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/tabill.service to /srv/tabill/tabill.service.
```

Now my service stops and starts whenever Postgres does. And naturally Postgres starts when the system boots.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a proper solution because your database does not really depend on your unit. Essentially you formed a two-way dependency while it is really a one-way. I think there is either a bug in systemd here or we are missing something.

Comment: It's not a dependency, it's just an instruction for systemd to start my service too. If my service fails to start, Postgres isn't affected by it.